# How do I calculate the length of a path from a weighted graph in Python?

Tags: python, graph

I am doing this project and I'm having a problem with finding out which path has the shortest length. The setup is a supermarket. You start at the entrance and you get out at the cash deck. The points A,B,C,D are the points in the sections in the supermarket like the bake-off etc. At the input 'via' you can give the points which you want to pass.

```
#e = entrance
#k = cash desk
graph1 = {'e':{'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':6, 'd':6},
    'a':{'e':2, 'b':4, 'c':5, 'd':5, 'k':7},
    'b':{'e':5, 'a':5, 'c':3, 'd':5, 'k':6},
    'c':{'e':6, 'a':5, 'b':3, 'd':4, 'k':5},
    'd':{'e':6, 'a':3, 'b':5, 'c':4, 'k':2},
    'k':{'a':7, 'b':6, 'c':5, 'd':2}
}

start = input('start')
end = input('end')
required = input('via').split(',')

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
  path = path + [start]
  if start == end:
      return [path]
  if not start in graph:
      return []
  paths = []
  for node in graph[start]:
      if node not in path:
          newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
          for newpath in newpaths:
              paths.append(newpath)
  return paths

def exists_in_graph(graph, nodes):
  for node in nodes:
    if not node in graph:
      return False
  return True

allPaths = find_all_paths(graph1, start, end)
allPathsTroughNodes = list(filter(lambda x: exists_in_graph(x, required), 
allPaths))
print(allPathsTroughNodes)
```

The output:

```
start e
end k
via a,c,d
[['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k'], ['e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'a', 
'c', 'b', 'd', 'k'], ['e', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'k'], ['e', 'a', 'c', 'd', 
'k'], ['e', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'k'], ['e', 
'a', 'd', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'k'], ['e', 'b', 'a', 'd', 
'c', 'k'], ['e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'k'], ['e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k'], 
['e', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'k'], ['e', 'c', 
'a', 'b', 'd', 'k'], ['e', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'k'], ['e', 'c', 'a', 'd', 
'k'], ['e', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'k'], ['e', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'k'], ['e', 
'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'k'], ['e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k'], ['e', 'c', 'd', 'b', 
'a', 'k'], ['e', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'k'], 
['e', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'k'], ['e', 'd', 'b', 
'c', 'a', 'k'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'k'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'k'], 
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'k']]
```

But I have no clue how I can calculate the length of each found path and how I can get the shortest one out of these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accumulate the path lengths while you're building the paths. It's possible to modify your existing code to do that, but it gets messy. A cleaner way to do this is to convert your function into a generator so that it yields paths as it finds them, rather than storing them in a list of paths.

We can pass the generator output to the `sorted` function to get a list of paths sorted by their length.

```
import sys

graph1 = {
    'e': {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 6},
    'a': {'e': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 5, 'd': 5, 'k': 7},
    'b': {'e': 5, 'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 5, 'k': 6},
    'c': {'e': 6, 'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'd': 4, 'k': 5},
    'd': {'e': 6, 'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 4, 'k': 2},
    'k': {'a': 7, 'b': 6, 'c': 5, 'd': 2}
}

#start = input('start ')
#end = input('end ')
#required = input('via ').split(',')
#if required == ['']:
    #required = []

# Hard-code some input data to make it easier to test the code
start, end = 'e', 'k'
required = []

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=None, pathlen=0):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        yield pathlen, path
    if not start in graph:
        yield [], 0
        return

    for node, val in graph[start].items():
        if node not in path:
            yield from find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path, pathlen + val)

def exists_in_graph(graph, nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        if not node in graph:
            return False
    return True

if not exists_in_graph(graph1, [start, end] + required):
    print('Bad data!')
    sys.exit()

all_paths = sorted(find_all_paths(graph1, start, end))
for pathlen, path in all_paths:
    if exists_in_graph(path, required):
        print(path, pathlen)
```

**output**

```
['e', 'a', 'd', 'k'] 8
['e', 'a', 'k'] 8
['e', 'd', 'k'] 8
['e', 'a', 'b', 'k'] 11
['e', 'a', 'c', 'k'] 11
['e', 'b', 'k'] 11
['e', 'c', 'k'] 11
['e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'k'] 12
['e', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'k'] 12
['e', 'b', 'd', 'k'] 12
['e', 'c', 'd', 'k'] 12
['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'k'] 13
['e', 'b', 'c', 'k'] 13
['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k'] 14
['e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k'] 14
['e', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'k'] 15
['e', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'k'] 15
['e', 'c', 'b', 'k'] 15
['e', 'd', 'c', 'k'] 15
['e', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'k'] 16
['e', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'k'] 16
['e', 'd', 'a', 'k'] 16
['e', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'k'] 17
['e', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'k'] 17
['e', 'b', 'a', 'k'] 17
['e', 'd', 'b', 'k'] 17
['e', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'k'] 18
['e', 'c', 'a', 'k'] 18
['e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'k'] 19
['e', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'k'] 19
['e', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'k'] 19
['e', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'k'] 19
['e', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'k'] 19
['e', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'k'] 19
['e', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'k'] 19
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'k'] 19
['e', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'k'] 20
['e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'k'] 20
['e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'k'] 20
['e', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'k'] 20
['e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k'] 20
['e', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'k'] 21
['e', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'k'] 21
['e', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'k'] 21
['e', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'k'] 21
['e', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'k'] 21
['e', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'k'] 21
['e', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'k'] 21
['e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k'] 22
['e', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'k'] 22
['e', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'k'] 22
['e', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'k'] 23
['e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'k'] 23
['e', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'k'] 23
['e', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'k'] 23
['e', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'k'] 24
['e', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'k'] 24
['e', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'k'] 25
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'k'] 25
['e', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'k'] 26
['e', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'k'] 26
['e', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'k'] 26
['e', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'k'] 27
['e', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'k'] 27
```

Another way to call the `find_all_paths` generator is

```
valid_paths = sorted((pathlen, path)
    for pathlen, path in find_all_paths(graph1, start, end)
        if exists_in_graph(path, required)
)
for pathlen, path in valid_paths:
    print(path, pathlen)
```

That way we can filter the unwanted paths before they get sorted. And if you just want the shortest path you can replace the call to `sorted` with `min`.

```
pathlen, path = min((pathlen, path)
    for pathlen, path in find_all_paths(graph1, start, end)
        if exists_in_graph(path, required)
)
print(path, pathlen)
```

**output**

```
['e', 'a', 'd', 'k'] 8
```

---

I've made a couple of other small changes to your code.

If the user enters nothing at the `'via'` prompt then `required` is set to a list containing the empty string, and that will mess up your `exists_in_graph` test, so if that happens we set `required` to the empty list.

In your version of `find_all_paths` you give `path` a default value of the empty list. That will mess things up if you want to call `find_all_paths` more than once, because default args are evaluated when the function is created, not when it's called. So if you call `find_all_paths` again without supplying a `path` arg it will continue using the same default `path` list that it originally used, it *won't* use a new empty list. The usual way to deal with this is to use a default of `None`, as I've done in my code. For more info on this important topic, please see [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).